# Will the app file be sync from dmgr side after we remove it from installedApps path in Websphere?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

Do you know whether the app file will be sync from dmgr side and regenerated after we remove it from installedApps path?

I have got one issue recently from customer, that is, they uploaded one image file into WASNode **`installedApps`** app path **`manually`**. Afterwards, they removed that file manually again from **`installedApps`** app path. But after restarting the Application server process, that file has been regenerated under same **`installedApps`** path.

So I suspect that file maybe has been resync from dmgr node, like app file under **`applications`** folder. However, first of all, I don't see that image file within application ear file from DMGR **`applications`** folder. Moreover, I made a test myself, if I deleted file from **`installedApps`** app path, that file never be regenerated any more even though the node sync completed.

So does anybody know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, when they added the file manually, you mean not the single file upload through the admin console, but something like FTP to the directory, correct?

Comment: @dbreaux yes, it's not through admin console but like FTP way.

Answer (score 1):

This is all product internals and can't be relied upon.  My observation has been that installing an application creates `DMGR_HOME/config/cells/CELL/applications/APP.ear/APP.ear`.  During node sync, this file is copied to the same location in each node agent, then `NODE_HOME/installedApps/CELL/APP.ear` is deleted, and the EAR is re-expanded.

In your example, you would need to modify the application such that the EAR is modified (e.g., `AdminApp.update`, or possibly modifying a binding) in order to force the EAR to be re-expanded when syncing the node.  I have no theory for how the image file would show up if it doesn't exist in the dmgr.